# MVN jmeter Hashtree I/O error for running through java code

Tags: java, jmeter, blazemeter, hashtree

Pretty new to jmeter and i am trying to Run an existing JMeter Test from Java code i read from the link below.

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui

But when i try to follow the instruction im getting a java error. Can someone point out what im doing wrong? Im pretty new to this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The message is pretty clear. `SaveService#loadTree` no longer accepts an input stream, it wants a file. The link you're referring to was written a couple of years ago, at the time it used a version of the library that still accepted an input stream.

Change

```
FileInputStream test = new FileInputStream("src/test/jmeter/ssoLogin.jmx");
```

to

```
File test = new File("src/test/jmeter/ssoLogin.jmx");
```

Comment: Thanks i actually tried that but then it couldnt resolve the method close for test.close(). So im not srue if running jmeter this way will work.

Comment: So i tried running it and this is what i got. 

116 [main] INFO org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils - Setting Locale to en_US
1102 [main] INFO org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService - Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
1181 [main] ERROR org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService - Can't compute checksum for saveservice properties file
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\test\jmeter\bin\saveservice.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)